# Backbone events and d3

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js, jquery-svg

So I have a histogram that I have created in backbone and I am trying to use backbone's events hash to register click events.

However, these events aren't firing, and from reading around, this is because the SVG dom is different from the DOM jquery uses.

I looked at the jquery-svg plugin as a way around, but am now not sure how to use this plugin in conjunction with the events hash.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to bind events the D3 way?